# What to do with gathered saliva while Meditating

Tags: meditation-recommendation

While meditating today I found that the gathered saliva was bothering me a lot. I do not know why it just came up today. It was distracting and took me away from my concentration a few times . I swallowed it . 
What should I do when this happens again in the future? How should one keep the tongue and do with the saliva?

Answer (score 1):

Haha, spit it out and use it as an in-vivo object for the asubha bhavana practise (loathsomeness of the body).